# Is there a way to return each value as a row in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi we know that is we do the following query in Oracle SQL we get each value as a column and will return the value as value in each column.

```
select 'Draft','Submitted','Cancelled','Accepted','Accepted and Modified','Open','Pending','Seller Reject' from dual;
```

Is there a way to return each value as a new row under single column?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - any links for reference?

Comment: type this into google: "oracle crosstab query"

Comment: Why not create a table ( or view ) of this data then select from that?

Comment: @Ben - we give patch scripts to the client, so I cannot create tables on client DB if they are not used by the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it works:

```
select 'Draft' as Enum
union
select 'Submitted' as Enum
union
select 'Cancelled' as Enum
union
select 'Accepted' as Enum
union
select 'Accepted and Modified' as Enum
union
select 'Open' as Enum
union
select 'Pending' as Enum
union
select 'Seller Reject' as Enum
```

This will work on SQL Server.

But for oracle, please add the from claus in each select query like `select 'Seller Reject' as Enum from Dual`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to avoid this much of SQL. looking for simple way.

Comment: @Pokuri: this looks like a simple enough way to me (but doesn't each unioned result require a `FROM` clause in Oracle i.e. `FROM dual`?) because it uses simple relational operators. Please reconsider whether "this much of SQL" is really a bad thing.

Comment: @onedaywhen: I just updated my answer. Thanks for pointing out the oracle issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table (
  sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Draft','Submitted','Cancelled','Accepted','Accepted and Modified','Open','Pending','Seller Reject')
);
```